# Symbols in keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been searching how to write in Elementary OS symbols which don't appear on the keyboard, I mean," £ ", "♣ " , " ♥ ".

I used lots of years Windows and they can be written by pressing ALT + (number). For instance ALT + 3 is ♥.

So I've tried with the ALT method but it doesn't work. I found on the net that Unicode symbols can be written by Shift + Ctrl + ( u , number), but this doesn't work for me neither.

Could you tell me how to do it? Thanks a lot in advance.